# Does OAuth security for Azure API Management require a separate API for each client app that wants to use the API with OAuth security?

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, azure-api-management

I was able to secure my API in API Management instance using OAuth 2.0 and Active Directory by [following this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad). However, this only works for one client application that was configured in the OAuth connection. So my question is this

Given that

1. OAuth connection is tied to a specific client app

[image]

2. Only one OAuth connection can be set for an API

[image]
does this mean that we have to have a separate instance of an API for each client that wants to use the API with OAuth security?

Answer (score 0):

When you enable authentication and authorization for your api management instance using azure active directory , you must have created an app registration in your AAD tenant which represents your api. Navigate to the app registration select **expose an api** from left pane and the blade which opens has an option at the bottom **add client application**.
This option allows you to add client application which can request the api as a scope.